# Trying to center a FormView in the browser window using ASP.Net with Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Okay, I haven't posted much here before, but I'm struggling with something that I think shouldn't be that hard.  I have most of a form in an AJAX content template.  When I click on a row in the GridView, it activates a FormView to edit the record.  I want to center the FormView in the browser window.  I've tried using jQuery but obviously, I'm not refreshing the document, so my jQuery center function in Document Ready isn't activating. I somehow need to activate it when the content template update, I think. Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

As an alternative would be to position the FormView (or panel around it) based on the row selected, I suppose, but that isn't my first choice.

Comment: When you say "centered in the browser window", do you mean you want it to pop up in front of everything else (like a [modal popup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)), or just have it centered in it's existing position on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of document.ready, use this:

```
function pageLoad() {
     //--- code here
}
```

This will allow your jquery function to fire when you click into the form mode. If your jquery code is correct, we don't know because you didn't post your code.

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: I kept looking and was able to resolve the problem. What I was looking for was the PageLoadedEventHandler() function. This executes after the partial postback.  Sorry! I had been struggling with this for hours, and I can usually find a solution just searching. It helped to type out the question.

Comment: Were you saying to execute the script in pageLoad?  I guess I don't know what you mean, but I'd like to know alternative ways to do it.

Comment: You can use the javascript function pageLoad() and the code within will fire on every postback and partial postback. I thought your problem was the code wouldn't execute because you had it in document.ready, which only executes the first time the page is loaded. Putting the code into the function pageLoad() would allow the code to fire on the partial postback.